# How to build webpack on heroku?

Tags: heroku, webpack

What is the best way to trigger Webpack build after deploying to Heroku?

Push already bundled version in not the most beautiful solution.

Answer (score 5):

What kind of application is this? If you are using a package.json, you could run webpack in the postinstall step using npm scripts.

Comment: I'm compiling webpack programatically (from my index.js) and it works only on my local machine. Makes sense, aren't dynos' filesystem supposed to be read-only?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by placing devDependencies in normal dependencies, and I changed the postinstall script to:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `postinstall` in your package.json to the following `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p`

Then set `start` to `node`

But you will need to make sure to config your webpack for production either by setting it within your webpack.config.js or webpack.config.js(production) as a production config.

I set everything within my webpack.config.js as follows..

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";


module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  module: {
    loader: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['angular']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
     }]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: 'src'
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: {except: ['$', 'exports', 'require', 'app']},
    compress: {warnings: false},
    sourceMap: false
  })
  ]
}
```

so basically, once the command runs `npm run postinstall`  bundle will be generated in the directory as per webpack.config.js (output). But remember to include in your package.json with the commands `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p` before running 'npm start'. See example below..

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/bundle.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server.js",
    "postinstall": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": ...
```